# Asana Events API always returning invalid sync token in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, asana-api

I am trying to call the Asana Events API - https://developers.asana.com/reference/getevents

This endpoint uses a 'Sync' token to track when you last called it, each call returns a new sync token which can then be stored and used for the next call to only retrieve events since the last call.

If you do not provide a sync token the API will return an 'invalid token' response and give you a new token to get started with.

However, I cannot seem to get it beyond the initial 'invalid token' call, when I used the token in the following call it still returns 'invalid token'

This is using Google's Apps Script, which is basically just JavaScript with some built-in Google functions

Here is my code:

This function makes a call without the ‘sync’ parameter, uses muteHttpExceptions to get the full response text, and sets the sync token as a property in Apps Script (just a key/value pair)

```
var asanaBaseUrl = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0'

function getSyncToken() {
  var url = asanaBaseUrl + '/projects/' + asanaProject + '/events'

  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + asanaPAT
  }

  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': headers,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }

  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var data = JSON.parse(r.getContentText())


  var newSyncToken = data.sync
  userProps.setProperty('syncToken', newSyncToken)

}
```

This function uses the properties service to pull the sync token set in the previous call and makes a new call with the sync parameter

```
function asanaEventCall() {
  var url = asanaBaseUrl + '/projects/' + asanaProject + '/events'
  var syncToken = userProps.getProperty('syncToken')

  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + asanaPAT
  }

  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': headers,
    'sync': syncToken,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var data = JSON.parse(r.getContentText())
  return data
}
```

The second function always returns the following

```
{sync=[SYNC TOKEN HERE], errors=[{message=Sync token invalid or too old. If you are attempting to keep resources in sync, you must fetch the full dataset for this query now and use the new sync token for the next sync.}]}
```

I’ve confirmed that the token is being set, retrieved, and sent correctly using the logs.

I’ve confirmed the flow above works by manually using the URL, like this:

- Go to [https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/[PROJECT](https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/%5BPROJECT) GID]/events
- Copy sync token
- Go to [https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/[PROJECT](https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/%5BPROJECT) GID]/events?sync=[SYNC TOKEN]
- Events show properly

I've looked for other answers but haven't found anything specific that helped, and I asked on the Asana forum but haven't got an answer in a few days.

I'm sure I'm missing something painfully obvious here but just can't see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Go to https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/[PROJECT GID]/events?sync=[SYNC TOKEN]` of `I’ve confirmed the flow above works by manually using the URL, like this:`, in your script, it seems that it is required to add `'sync': syncToken,` as the query parameter. So, how about modifying your `asanaEventCall()` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```
function asanaEventCall() {
  var syncToken = userProps.getProperty('syncToken')
  var url = asanaBaseUrl + '/projects/' + asanaProject + '/events' + '?sync=' + syncToken;
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + asanaPAT
  }
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'headers': headers,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var data = JSON.parse(r.getContentText())
  return data
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your values of `asanaProject`, `asanaPAT` and `syncToken` are valid values. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Oh my god, I know it would be something like this, thank you! I was sure I had tried that but I guess not because it just worked!